# How to debug this facebook API error

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

> FBConditionalLog: System authorization failed:'The Facebook server
>   could not fulfill this access request: remote_app_id does not match
>   stored id '. This may be caused by a mismatch between the bundle
>   identifier and your app configuration on the server at
>   developers.facebook.com/apps.

The bundle identifier is com.domainname

In developers.facebook.com/apps.

Okay, so I am going to debug this.

I want to know the value of remote_app_id

Then I want to know the value of stored id.

How do I do so?

Comment: Well I'm not sure if you can access the debug information you're looking for (as process carries out on Facebook servers) but the error message is quite clear. Check you bundle identifier and look at the registered bundle identifier on developer.facebook.com

Comment: They are the same and the answer is I just have to wait for a while. Should I delete this question or make that as an answer?

Comment: Good you solved it that easily. I'd suggest you mark your own answer as the answer

Comment: Is it a legitimate way to get points? I solve something reasonably interesting and I already know the answer and I share that in QA format for quick points?

Comment: Well I've seen many examples where the author of the question answered himself. I'd suggest you elaborate your answer, make it more clear and mark it as answer. I haven't read every rule of SO but I've seen many examples and it should be just fine. It will be a problem if you start abusing this of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found out how to debug is.

However, what I did is check what the bundle id is in my project. Then I go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and make sure the bundle id of my project is the same.

Then I wait a few minutes.

My problem was that I didn't wait.

It took a while before facebook propagate the bundle id everywhere.